# How to import folder files and their class in different files in Python?

Tags: python, module

I am working on a big project using Python as a backend. Initially, when no.of files were few, it went fine. But as files, folders increase lots of issues come in importing them.

I have below project structure and I also mention their class and function used inside it.

```
RealTimeConsumerAPI/
            __init__.py
            consumers/
                    __init__.py
                    consumerupdater.py    --- (class ConUpdater, class ConTracker)
                    consumerdeleter.py    --- (class ConDeleter, class ConRemover)

                    account/
                    __init__.py
                    acccountinfo.py       --- (class AccInfo)
                    accountsummary.py     --- (def summary, class AccSummary)


            producers/
                    __init__.py
                    producerupdater.py    --- (class ProUpdater, class ProMaker)
                    producerdeleter.py    --- (class ProDeleter, class ProRemover)

            material.py                   --- (class MaterialMaker, class MaterialEnhance)

            transport.py                  --- (def Vehicle.py, class TransportFare)
```

Now I don't know what should I mention in **init**.py file of each and how to import class, function in different files and folders. Please answers with detailed solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you check one of the multiple online guides to import statements. 
[This one](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html) seems quite comprehensive. Especially [this section](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html#all-about-__init__py).